# Formule with reference to another workbook

Tags: phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I have two files:
File1.xls with data in column F36 -> 1000.00
Empty file File2.xls

I'm trying to reference file1 inside file2 -> A1. Meaning I will have the value of [File1.xls]F36 in [File2.xls] A1.

For this I'm using the following code but this is generating the error:

Error:

```
        PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Calculation\Exception
        Blad1!A1 -> Unable to access External Workbook
```

Code:

```
        $spreadSheet = IOFactory::load('c:\\file2.xls');
        
        $workSheet = $spreadSheet->getActiveSheet(1);
        
        $spreadSheet->getActiveSheet(1)->setCellValue(
            'A1',
            "=c:\\[file1.xls]Sheet1!F36"
        );
```

What am I missing here guys?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did my response help?

Comment: That exception is thrown when PhpSpreadsheet is running the calculation steps and accessing another workbook is currently unsupported (March 2024). I managed to save the file by turning off calculation with

$writer->setPreCalculateFormulas(false);

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest setting the value in `File2.xls` manually (in such a way that you can visually verify it actually works), and then use PHP to read back the cell value/formula in `File2.xls` and use that value as the input for what you currently have. Other than this I can only suggest using case sensitive file names.. PHP/Excel may be case-sensitive where the windows OS is not, i.e. `file2.xls` -> `File2.xls` and `file1.xls` -> `File1.xls`